# Array in a memory-constrained system

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management, programming-languages

Consider that my system has memory, but it is scattered in different places (fragmented). There are no four contiguous memory locations that are free. In that scenario, if I declare a character array of size 10 in the C language, what will happen ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If *"my system has memory, but it is scattered in different places(fragmented)"* means, that [heap virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_memory_allocation) is fragmented, and *"declare a character array of size 10"* means, that you create character array of size 10 in [stack memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation):

```
char str[10];
```

, then array will be successfully created.

If *"declare a character array of size 10"* means, that you allocate memory with malloc() (allocate in heap):

```
char *str2;
str2 = (char*) malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
```

, then malloc() will return NULL.

Answer (score 2):

If all of your memory including the stack is fragmented like this, you either have a compiler (or runtime system) that supports non-contiguous stacks—in which case it *might* also be smart enough to support non-contiguous arrays—or basically everything you do (like calling subroutines) will result in a stack overflow and crash your program.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your response. So, incase of a fragmented stack, a compiler that supports non-contiguous stacks seems to solve the problem. Does gcc support non-contiguous stack ? Can you let me know a good compiler flavour that supports non-contiguous stack ?